# How do I convert Rally DragAndDropRank field to numeric rank in rally grid?

Tags: gridview, sdk, rally, appsdk2

I am trying to read DragAndDropRank field of a portfolio item to display it as its equivalent numeric Rank in my grid. Something like P!!%h~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ would be rendered as its respective rank. How do I achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct translation between DragAndDropRank and the numeric value.  All of the grids in the product that show the rank column and a numeric value in each row are just rendering the row index for that value.